# Fn key doesn't work on ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: keyboard

In Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS version, the Fn key remains fixed and does not work.
https://gist.github.com/andrebrait/961cefe730f4a2c41f57911e6195e444
I tried to run the advice according to the link above, but there is no directory called hid_apple, only the directory called hid, hid_generic.
I've looked up a lot of other tips, but they're all just asking me to modify the hid_apple. How do I solve this situation?

Comment: I can't confirm that "the Fn key remains fixed and does not work". Fn behavior is hardware specific.

Comment: @Pilot6 Literally, the fn key is always held in use. Pressing the fn key to use the function key (F1~F12) does not respond. In other words, it is always held in use regardless of pressing the fn key.

Comment: Is it a laptop keyboard, or an external keyboard?

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm sorry I didn't metion anything about my environment. I use desktop and external keaboard connected wireless.

Comment: You need to check the keyboard manual and test it with another OS. I don't think it is related to Ubuntu. Also please add details to your question including the keyboard model. The question title is incorrect.